# How to distinguish between a text search and a voice search?

Tags: android, searchview

I'm developing an Android app and want to distinguish in the Search activity (which gets the intent) if the user entered the text via keyboard or via the voice recognition feature of the SearchView (AppCompat). How can I distinguish between those two?

Answer (score 1):

In my app, I determine this by checking to see if the value of `SearchManager.USER_QUERY` is null. If it is, that means the user did not type any text to initiate the search, which means that they used voice search. I do it like this:

```
@Override
protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
    if (intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_SEARCH)) {

        //if this was a voice search
        if (intent.getStringExtra(SearchManager.USER_QUERY) == null) {
            //do stuff with voice search query...
        } else {
            //perform search with text query
        }

    }
}
```

This solution has always felt hacky to me, but it's the only way I could figure out to do it and it's been working flawlessly ever since I implemented it.

Answer (score 0):

For the search to get populated via voice does the user have to click on a button to speak?

Comment: Yes. The user clicks the microphone icon in the Toolbar (AppCompat) instead of typing text, which then pops ups the system voice reconigtion dialog.

Comment: So when you start the search Activity you can include intent.putExtra(EXTRA_MESSAGE, message);
    startActivity(intent);
as an identifier from the activity that is launching the search activity.

Comment: And in the search activity check it this way Intent intent = getIntent();  String message = intent.getStringExtra(MyActivity.EXTRA_MESSAGE); And you can compare the string. It need not be a string value, can be of a different data type - whatever suits you